# Como verificar se existe algum post em determinada categoria

Tags: php, wordpress

Gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar, estou tentando verificar se existe algum post em determinada categoria para fazer validação e if e esle, entretanto sem muito sucesso até o momento.

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php if ( have_posts("cat=13") ) { ?>
<?php query_posts("cat=13&showposts=9&paged=$paged"); ?>

Sucesso

} else {

Falhou

?>
<?php } ?>   
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

Comment: Quando vc diz um post, é se vc recebeu algum dado via post ?, se for isso tem assim `if(!empty($_POST['cat'])) { //tem post }`

Comment: Não algum dado e sim literalmente o post

Comment: Tenta mostra um exemplo de como seria o resultado se tiver um post ou quando não tem, que fica mais fácil de se fazer a validação

Comment: Se existir algum post em determinada categoria ele exibe o post normal, mas caso não exista nenhum post nessa categoria exibe uma imagem informando que ainda está em implantação

Answer (score 0):

Tenta verificar se post_count é maior que 0. Se sim, sucesso. Se não, não tem post.

Mais info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Comment: Estou tentando utilizar já retorno com o que aconteceu

Comment: Consegui, porém fiz de uma outra forma era so acrescentar um { no meu codigo no local certo para funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado por que tentou me ajudar, já consegui resolver, caso alguem necessite de algo parecido, segue o codigo:

```
<?php $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; ?>
<?php query_posts("cat=13&showposts=9&paged=$paged"); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ){ while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 

Sucesso

} else {

Falhou

?>
<?php } ?>   
<?php wp_reset_query();?>
```